# Using headphone out to hook an alarm clock app to speakers

Tags: alarm, archos-gen8, headphone-jack

I own an Archos 43 Internet Tablet running Android 2.2, and I am looking either for an application or configuration option to allow using the headphone out port (if it is plugged in) for the alarm in an alarm clock app.
I'd like to hook my Android device to external speakers in order to make the alarm louder than the device's internal speaker is capable of reaching.
The ability to use the math alarm option would be nice, as well.

I've tried the integrated alarm clock, as well as the free version of "Alarm Clock Plus".  Neither of them seem to output the sound to the headphone port in their current configurations.

I am not opposed to spending money if I know that it will work as a viable solution.

Any feedback or solutions?

Answer (score 3):

I just tried with my Archos 70 and alarm clock plus v2 and it didn't seem to work at first but when I played with the headphone-jack and pulled it out about half a millimeter and it worked.  This would seem to be a problem with the jack, but it works just fine when playing videos or music.  I think the issue might be that the alarm clock apps are sending the audio out on just one channel and it's not getting picked up for some reason by the stereo speakers.  I remember I used to have a similar problem with my old walkman and certain headphones and I'd have to pull the jack out just a little bit.  I know theory doesn't make complete sense because it still should work just out of one speaker but it's something I've noticed about 3.5" headphone jacks for years and can't explain it.

Also, if you don't want to mess around with playing with the depth of the jack or trying a mono speaker, you could set the Alarm Clock Plus to launch Pandora which would probably play just fine over the stereo speakers.

Comment: I would think it's deliberate rather than a problem. For those times you fall asleep listening to music, but still want to be woken up even when the earphones fall out when you roll over. Pulling the jack out a bit stops it detecting the headphones are even there (they've probably gone mono instead of stereo too).

Comment: Hmmm, this may be the case but I don't like that very much.  At the very least they should make that optional.